# Query a distinct value where a columnA != columnB

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to select the group_ID of groups which `ID = '12-027-013'` is not a part of.

I have tried  this query.

```
SELECT DISTINCT groups.group_ID, groups.group_name 
FROM groups INNER JOIN group_member 
ON groups.group_ID = group_member.group_ID 
WHERE groups.group_name LIKE "%e%" 
AND group_member.ID != "12-027-013"
```

But it still displays groups that `ID = '12-027-013'` are already part of.

These are my tables

TABLE: **groups**

[image]

TABLE: **group_member**

[image]

This is the result of my query

[image]

Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the best approach is simply a `LEFT JOIN`:

```
SELECT g.group_ID, g.group_name 
FROM groups g LEFT JOIN
     group_member gm
     ON gm.group_ID = g.group_ID  AND
        gm.ID = '12-027-013'
WHERE g.group_name LIKE '%e%' AND
      gm.group_ID IS NULL;
```

This doesn't have a `DISTINCT`, so it should perform much better than your original query.

An similar alternative is `NOT EXISTS`:

```
SELECT g.*
FROM groups g 
WHERE g.group_name LIKE '%e%' AND
      NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM group_member gm
                  WHERE gm.group_ID = g.group_ID  AND
                        gm.ID = '12-027-013'
                 );
```

Both these version can make use of indexes on `groups(group_name, group_id)` and `group_member(group_id, id)` for optimal performance.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  groups.group_ID,
  groups.group_name
FROM groups
  INNER JOIN group_member
    ON groups.group_ID = group_member.group_ID
  LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT group_id FROM group_member WHERE group_member.ID = "12-027-013") gm ON group_member.group_id=gm.group_id
WHERE groups.group_name LIKE "%e%"
  AND gm.group_id IS null
```

Comment: It worked! Thank you very much. Although I'd like to know what does gm mean.

Comment: `gm` is the name given to a temporary or memory table of the sub-query. The `gm.group_id IS NULL` at the end subtracts the records of groups containing the `ID` in question

Comment: so basically gm refers (SELECT group_id FROM group_member WHERE group_member.ID = "12-027-013")?

Comment: yes, result set of execution of this sub-query is stored as a memory table and we've given it a name, `gm`, to access it when needed

Comment: Thank you very much. I get it now. I never knew that I could do that.

Comment: Although this query works, it is overly complicated.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT groups.group_ID, groups.group_name 
FROM groups INNER JOIN group_member 
ON groups.group_ID = group_member.group_ID 
WHERE groups.group_name LIKE "%e%" 
AND group_member.ID NOT LIKE "%12-027-013%" //if the type of id is text
```

The problem is in "!=". It should be NOT LIKE

Comment: The results are still the same.